# Where should I put comma and full stop?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

"Hi Jordan,

Greetings from XYZ Solutions,

I have analysed the content provided by you."

**OR**

"Hi Jordan.

Greetings from XYZ Solutions.

I have analysed the content provided by you."

Which one is correct?

Comment: You should really start by wondering where you should put paragraph breaks. Right now both variants are equally horrible.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.

> Hi Jordan,
>
> Greetings from XYZ Solutions.
> I have analysed the content provided by you.

Only put a comma after the person's name, not after the greeting.

Comment: Why not, "Hi, Jordan." ?

Comment: Because that's not how I was taught. Admittedly I was taught "Dear Jordan," but *hi* works the same as *dear* there.

Comment: I don't consider *hi* and *dear* the same, I guess. See this: http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/02/using_commas_wi.html

Comment: @JLG: she gives email opening lines as exceptions.